# Add constraint on a column based on another only for specific values

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a sql table named products that looks like this:

| p_id | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| SS100 | Smoked salmon 100g |
| FS50 | Fried shrimp 50g |
| MC400 | Mac and cheese 400g |
| SS300 | Smoked salmon 300g |

I need to add a constraint so that if p_name starts with Smoked salmon then the p_id must start with SS.

I tried using this:
CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (p_id LIKE 'SS%' AND p_name LIKE 'Smoked salmon%');
But that doesn't work since there are p_id and p_name with different values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an `OR` condition to the constraint as follows:

```sql
CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (p_name LIKE 'Smoked salmon%' AND p_id LIKE 'SS%'
                                OR p_name NOT LIKE 'Smoked salmon%');
```